# adobe connect add in not installed error in both chrome and firefox in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, flash, adobe

I participate in a virtual class which the basic software is Adobe Connect. I installed Adobe by software center and then try to connect got this message. and I tried to remove it and installed the Adobe flash player plugin by adobe website, also other websites was Ok but I have same problem in connecting to my V class. When I was using Ubuntu 12.04 I didn't have same problem. What's your suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go and download Google Chrome from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

It has built in versions of Adobe products.

Chromium and Firefox still use the Adobe Flash plugin that you install and it doesn't always work right I have found.

If you have Google Chrome installed then just uninstall all the adobe products you installed.

Comment: If I uninstall all adobe products,won't I fall in problem by firefox ?? because my main browser is firefox.

Comment: I have an Nvidia card so when I use flash and firefox everything is green.  That was my browser of choice, but it just doesn't work without some work arounds that will severally hurt system performance.

Comment: I installed chrome as you said, the result is same and disappointing. Maybe it's useful to mention when I was in ubuntu 12.04 I was using Nvidia for my Geforce 8400. When I choose Nvidia in ubuntu 12.10 OS goes freezing after booting. So I have to work with X.org. Is it possible this affect my adobe flash player performance ?

Comment: I study the Adobe connect add-in comments on its website which these ports should be open :

80,
90,
1935,
443,

I try to connect to adobe connect, I mean my class. at the same time I try to listen my network by
<<<<<netstat -an | grep "LISTEN ">>>>>
the result shows no attempt to connect these ports. And by this command <<<<  nmap -v scanme.nmap.org >>>>>, the result demonstrate these ports are just open <<<
22/tcp ;  open ; ssh;
80/tcp  ; open ; http;
9929/tcp ;open ; nping-echo ;>>>>. So? @goddard

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is shipping with a built-in Flash plugin. Even if you install manually Flash it will always use the version it's shipped with and also Adobe Connect won't open Connect Add-In.

Refer to the official Adobe Connect help site how to solve the problem:
http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/kb/google-chrome-browser-incompatibility-version.html